# Correlation of the sample as the estimation of parameter of Gaussian copula

Tags: correlation, estimation, covariance-matrix, copula

Given 3 variables $X, Y, Z$ and I assume that the multivariate distribution of them is a Gaussian copula.

Now I need to estimate the correlation matrix of the Gaussian copula. As in many textbooks, i see that the matrix of correlation of Gaussian copula is estimated by the Maximum Likelihood Estimator (or Pseudo - MLE).

I'am wondering whether I can estimate the correlation matrix of the copula as the covariance between the 3 variables $X, Y, Z$ ? (for example, to estimate parameter $\rho_{X, Y}$ of the correlation matrix, I take it to be Pearson's correlation of $X$ and $Y$ which can be calculated with the formula $\rho = \frac{\sum (x_i - \bar{x}).(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sqrt{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2 .\sum(y_i - \bar{y})^2}}$)

In other words, what is the difference between 2 methods of estimation above ? (i.e. estimation of matrix of correlation by MLE vs estimation of matrix of correlation by simply estimating correlation of each pair of variable, then fill in the correlation matrix).

Comment: Do you assume Gaussian marginal variables so the multivariate distribution is tri-variate Gaussian?

Comment: @Dave: hi, thanks for your comment. what I want to know is in the general case. So if there are differences between the case of gaussian marginal and non-gaussian marginal, could you please answer in 2 separate cases ? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: For copula, marginals do affect the copula choice. However, you can estimate the copula parameters using any valid estimation method. However, pearson correlation is weak itself and the question here is it invariant under increasing transformation function?

Comment: For copula, there is no difference if the marginal comes to form gaussian or not.

Comment: @Maryam: Hi, thanks for your comment. However, I don't understand what you mean in your comment. Can you the context which you refer to ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi. I answer your question in your comment to @Dave. So, for the copula estimation process, nothing will be changed due to the change of the marginal distribution. However, the estimation of the margins will affect the choice of copula type.

Comment: Kindly, I want you to ask a question which is: Why do we use copula here? Why not just Pearson correlation? Asking many questions, even you already know the answer, will improve your thinking and be a perfect way to find a solution.

Comment: Also, is there a direct relationship between Pearson correlation and copula?

Comment: @Maryam: Thanks for your comment. In fact, i have already questioned my self those questions before deciding to post a question on mathexchange. It is because i can't answer the question asked. If you have any answer, i would be very thankful if you can spend sometime write it, it will be very useful for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge Thanks, dear.  Ok. We use copula because it does not require a specific type of marginal distribution. That is, if you have two variables, $X_1$, and $X_2$, then $X_1$ can be from Gaussian distribution, while the marginal function of $X_2$ is t-student. Then, the measure of the dependency by copula will not be affected by the transformation of the margins (if you estimate them correctly).

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge   However, the Person correlation coefficient will not give you the desired measure of the dependency as it suffers from some limitations. For example, it requires all variables to be from a normal distribution.

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge By estimating them correctly, I meant that you need to make sure that the estimated margins are correct. That is because the estimation of the margins strongly affects the estimation of the copula function.

Comment: @Maryam, Pearson correlation does not assume normality.

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes, it is not. However, it gives a better result if both are marginal in normal! So, for me, it assumes normality!! There is a huge discussion about this point. It cannot deal with complex dependency.

Comment: The notion of a *better result* is context dependent. My point is that Pearson correlation is perfectly *valid* under nonnormality, and this is why the statement *it requires all variables to be from a normal distribution* seems quite misleading to me.